# Number of Hibernate Sessions Per Request or Per User?

Tags: hibernate

Consider that we are planning to develop a big enterprise application. In such a case what should be the best way for the following:

a) Number of Hibernate Sessions Per Request or Per User?
b) Number of Transactions permitted in an application?
c) Relationship between connection pooling and hibernate session?
d) Relationship between Hibernate Sessions and JTA transactions?
e) Does Number of Hibernate Session reduces the performances? If yes, what are the reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Per request. It is more scalable and allows physical JDBC connection pooling.

b) Each request will be one transaction. This transaction may span different transactional resources. In this case you are mostly interested for database. For each database a session will be created (assuming the database is accessed within the particular request). At the end of the request cycle either all transactional resources will be committed or none (two phase commit). In a managed environment (application server), the transactional resources are implicitly enlisted to the transaction that is taking place on the current thread when accessed. The user (your application) may interact with this transaction to set boundaries using the JTA api (see UserTransaction).

c) Each newly created Session will receive a connection from a connection pool.

d) At most one hibernate session for each database per JTA transaction

e) Yes. I assume that each Session is actually used to do something with the DB (see the above points). First reason is the natural bottleneck of application server and database server resources (CPU, memory, network). The second reason has to do with database locks (transaction scope) and, a bit indirectly, the used version locking scheme (conversation scope)

When outside the container you have to use a standalone connection pool / JTA implementation. One example is JOTM with XaPool. However, Hibernate has APIs for interaction with stuff like JOTM and C3P0 from what I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

a) For a single db you can create only one session factory and you can create any number of sessions.

b) Database (or system) transaction boundaries are always necessary. No communication with the database can occur outside of a database transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the auto-commit mode). Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for read-only operations. Depending on your isolation level and database capabilities this might not be required but there is no downside if you always demarcate transactions explicitly. You'll have to do operations outside a transaction, though, when you'll need to retain modifications in an EXTENDED persistence context.

c) A hibernate Session is a wrapper around a Connection in order to allow you to save your POJOs without directly writing the SQL.

A hibernate Session is a wrapper around a Connection. Connections are held in a connection pool.

When you call SessionFactory.openSession hibernate first takes a Connection from the supplied connection pool. It then creates a Session around that Connection and returns it.